# What video/audio codec settings for playback on Android and iOS

Tags: iphone, android, video, video-streaming

What codec settings will produce valid videos for playback on Android (videoView) and iOS UIWebView)?

Comment: I am mainly asking for iPhone 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android:  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

iOS video (UIWebView's don't actually play the videos, they pass it off to another class): http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953

and iOS audio: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW33