# Will IPhone 3 play videos encoded in H264 format?

Tags: iphone

Please point any good resources that talk at length on video formats

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456424/what-video-audio-codec-settings-for-playback-on-android-and-ios/3458515#3458515

Comment: The class reference states this is good for 2.0 and beyond.  Hope that helps!

Comment: This is more of a question about device capabilities than any programming issue, so Super User is probably a better fit for it.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer : YES

Long anwser :

> The video technologies in iOS support
>   the playback of movie files with the
>   .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename
>   extensions and using the following
>   compression standards:
>
> ```
> H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
> ```
>
> Low-Complexity version of the H.264
>   Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up
>   to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in
>   .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
>
> ```
>   H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second,
> ```
>
> Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with
>   AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz,
>   stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov
>   file formats
>
> ```
>   MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per
> ```
>
> second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC
>   audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo
>   audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file
>   formats

From [the official website](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW6)